# Does the amount of petrol affect your car's performance?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I've 'Realistic Fuel Consumption' turned on. E.g., if I fancy higher acceleration, ought I gas more often, but less each filling (and never a full tank)?

Comment: It doesn't afaik.